# Annotate Webpage using angular.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, annotations, nosql

I want to create a tool that **highlights the text in web page** and allow user to **comment** on it. We also need to store these annotations in some storage so that when user login next time, he can see the highlights & comments done by him. 
I want to know how should i store the data using NO-SQL db related to that annotation like comment info, start position, end position of text on particular page.

Comment: is this for any web page, or web pages on your site?

Comment: there are muliple pages of same kind. only data is different for each page.

Comment: is this for any web page, or web pages on your site?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/), [Annotator-PouchDB](http://github.com/bigbluehat/annotator-pouchdb), and [Hypothesis](http://hypothes.is/).

[Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/) is a library for doing annotation on HTML. It handles the selection, highlighting, and provides some commenting UI. There are extensions for tagging, [Web Annotation Data Model](http://w3.org/TR/annotation-model/) support, [and more](http://annotatorjs.org/plugins). The [Annotator-PouchDB](http://github.com/bigbluehat/annotator-pouchdb) storage plugin for Annotator would allow you to store annotations in the NoSQL databases that support the CouchDB HTTP API, such as [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/), [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), and [IBM's Cloudant](http://cloudant.com/).

Lastly, [Hypothesis](http://hypothes.is/) (and it's ["h" code](http://github.com/hypothesis/h)) is a more "out of the box" annotation solution that includes a heavily customized version of an older Annotator that supports PDF annotation and stores it's data in [ElasticSearch](http://elasticsearch.org/).

Hopefully something in there points you (or others) toward a workable solution!